# Heroku "Push rejected, failed to detect set buildpack heroku/ruby"

Tags: ruby, heroku

So i'm trying to push my work (Sinatra) to Heroku but keep getting the error `"Push rejected, failed to detect set buildpack heroku/ruby"`

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Facepalm* It seems like we have a rubberduck situation over here... kinda. Since I forgot to add a Gemfile. -.-'

Comment: Took me a while to find out that Gemfile in the Python context is `requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You should also make sure you're on the master branch or that you have have your Gemfile and package.json on your master branch when you push. I had the same error  using a heroku/python buildpack but I was not on the master branch. My master branch did not have a Procfile on there, so even though I saw a Procfile, heroku did not.